# current page number in JSF datatable pagination

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have implemeted datatable in JSF by looking at the below link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/lazy-jsf-primefaces-datatable_11.html

but for one of my requirement i need the current selected page. how can i get that ?

my exact requirement was to export to excel the current page for that i need data in the current page

can i get the current page data by using java script ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8255369/1199132)

Answer (score 2):

Considering the datatable below,

```
<p:dataTable id="dt" widgetVar="dtWv" value="#{viewMBean.list}" var="b" rows="2" paginator="true">
    <p:column>#{b.id}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{b.name}</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

You could get the current page using the widgetVar as follows:

```
dtWv.paginator.getCurrentPage();
```

Comment: sorry for late response. what should i do if i am using a HTML datatable ? i mean if i am using a HTML datatable and if i want to get the page number is there any way in java ?

Comment: That is a completely different situation. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I believe that the Primefaces Datatable is the best way to go.